# Backbone view events losing delegation on parent view re-render

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've seen this issue crop up a few times but haven't been able to solve it myself- or I don't quite understand the answers. Many things talk about using `.empty().append()` rather than `.html()` and stuff about making sure to always refer to the view's `$el` value rather than directly accessing the DOM. Still no dice.

If you take a look at this jsbin, you'll see that changing the select box value re-renders the wrapper view the first time, but then does nothing on subsequent changes- it loses its events.

http://jsbin.com/fuvoba/7/edit (apologies to any coffeescript haters)

Any idea why this could be happening?

Many thanks and internet pints in advance, as always :)

#### Edit- thought I'd include the code inline too:

```
class ArchivesDropdownView extends Backbone.View
  template: '<select><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select>'
  initialize: () ->
    console.log 'Initialised the select dropdown'
  render: () ->
    this.$el.find('#dropdown').empty().append @template
    console.log 'Rendered the select dropdown'
    return this
  events:
    'change select': 'updateSelect'
  updateSelect: () ->
    console.log 'Updated select dropdown.'
    wrapperView.render()


class WrapperView extends Backbone.View
  template: 'Please select: <div id="dropdown"></div><div id="random"><%=randomNum%></div>'
  render: () ->
    console.log 'Rendered the wrapper'

    this.$el.empty().append _.template(@template)(randomNum: Math.random())

    if !this.archivesDropdownView
      this.archivesDropdownView = (new ArchivesDropdownView().render())

    this.archivesDropdownView.render()

    return this


wrapperView = new WrapperView()
$('body').empty().append wrapperView.render().$el
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `this.archivesDropdownView.delegateEvents()` after appeding view `$el` to the other view.

```
  this.$el.find('#dropdown').empty().append this.archivesDropdownView.$el
  this.archivesDropdownView.delegateEvents()
```

But I don't like your architecture, you should use global reference from child view to render parent view. Use events instead, for example share the model between parent and child views and trigger event from child view to re-render parent view.

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/dehujecejape/1/edit

Comment: That does the job, thanks. And yeah I know the architecture of it is crappy, but that code is a stripped down version of a really, really old bit of code from a project- the rest of the code (and newer projects) are much better structured but I don't have the time to fully refactor this project to all use models and such :( delegateEvents works nicely for now though, cheers again.

Comment: I updated my answer by adding link to good architecture which has `delegateEvents` within the child view

Comment: Cheers for the update! Your new version renders the ArchivesDropdownView every time the value is changed; one of the original problems was that I wanted to render the subview only once and then append the cached view.$el when re-rendering the parent view. This is because in the real world version I have chosen running on the select box when rendering and it caused a kind of "flash" of an unstyled select element every time it rendered itself. Maybe that's a sign my architecture is worse than I thought ;)

Comment: Also the rerendering means that the select box loses its state, ie its currently selected option. This doesn't matter in the real application because I'm loading the selected value from elsewhere, but it's just a thought. I've utilised your version with the model and it works a treat so thanks, but it still creates that short flash whenever I re-render the view... :(

Comment: Then use 2 separate (not parent child) views and listen to the shared model events to re-render value view on change select view.

Answer (score 1):

You have this kind of problem because you don't do things the way they are supposed to be done. Why would you re-render entire container when one of its components change? Of course you will have all kinds of troubles with this approach.

I'd recommend you create a third component, and update it on select box change:

```
class ArchivesDropdownView extends Backbone.View      
  template: '<select><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select>'
  initialize: (opts)->
    console.log 'Initialised the select dropdown'    
    @listener = opts.listener
  render: ->
    console.log 'Rendered the select dropdown'
    @$el.html @template    
  events:
    'change': 'updateSelect'
  updateSelect: ->
    @listener.render()

class RandomGeneratorView extends Backbone.View
  template: '<%=randomNum%>'
  render: ->
    @$el.html _.template(@template)(randomNum: Math.random())    

class WrapperView extends Backbone.View
  template: 'Please select: <div id="dropdown"></div><div id="random"></div>'
  initialize: ->
    console.log "wrapper init"
    randomElement = new RandomGeneratorView()
    @randomGeneratorView = randomElement.render()
    @archivesDropdownView = (new ArchivesDropdownView(listener: randomElement)).render()

  render: ->
    @$el.html @template  
    @randomContainer = @$el.find "#random"
    @dropdownContainer = @$el.find "#dropdown"
    @dropdownContainer.html @archivesDropdownView
    @randomContainer.html @randomGeneratorView
    @$el

$('body').html (new WrapperView()).render()
```

Here's a [modified JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gemutagaloho/8/edit)